# Mapping someip:port to a someip/suburl

Tags: networking, port, tunnel

I would like it so that when my router gets a request for

```
http://192.168.0.33/plex
```

it basically returns

```
http://192.168.0.33:32400
```

I'm wondering if this is possible and if some routers do it.

Is this what is referred to as tunneling?

Comment: To give a more specific answer than @Ignacio, we need to know make and model. Depending on their web server and their configuration interface, it may be possible. To learn more about [Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) or [Proxying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) check out Wikipedia or the [web server's manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

If the location of the client is changed to the new URL then it is called **redirecting**.

If the contents at the new URL are read and returned to the client at the old URL then it is called **proxying**.